# Checking a wiki link using regexp

Tags: java, regex

I am not good at regexp. I am trying to check a wiki link. If it has a hashtag #, then I do not want to use it because it is within the current page.

Example:

```
[[Ball]]         -- OK
[[a ball |Ball]] -- OK
[[#Ball]]        -- No
```

What I have done sounds pretty simple,
so I have a string called a `link.matches("^#")`. It matches with everything except # but when tested with [[Ball]], it didn't work pretty well.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link.matches()` checks the entire string. One way to solve your problem is to check that the entire link only contains non-`#` characters:

```
if (link.matches("[^#]+") {
    //all ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also explicitly check for the occurrence of the # with find, or in your case even with indexOf of string:

```
if (link.indexOf("#") == 0) {
    // all good
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(?=\[\[[a-z]).*
```

That match links that doesn't start with `#`.

Also, don't forget to escape `\`